# This C# public method is not returning a value

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have three classes, and the code is provided below.

Network - Add and Remove Phone, Process Calls. Phone1 and Phone2 can call each other when added to the network.

But I am having an issue when I am connecting both the phone to the network and trying to call phone1 to phone2; it is keeping giving me "receiver busy". I have tried to do a little debugging and read the status of phone2 when calling from phone1, but it returns an empty string (which should actually return "A", when it is added to the network as I am setting its value to "A").

```
public partial class network : Form
{
    phone1 p1 = new phone1();
    phone2 p2 = new phone2();
    public network()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Boolean numberValidator(int number)
    {
        Boolean exist = false;
        if (comboBox2.Items.Equals(number))
        {
            exist = true;
        }

        return exist;
    }

    public void processCall(int rNumber)
    {
        if (!numberValidator(rNumber))
        {
            p1.TextBox1.Clear();
            p1.TextBox1.Text = "Not connected";
        }

        else
        {
            p1.TextBox1.Clear();
            p1.TextBox1.Text = "Call in progress";
            p2.receiveCall(1);
            p1.setStatus("Busy");
            /*
            if (p2.btnCallPressStatus())
            {
            p1.TextBox1.Clear();

            p1.TextBox1.Text = "Call initiated";
            }*/
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            p1.Show();
            comboBox2.Items.Add(1);
            p1.setStatus("A");
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            p2.Show();
            comboBox2.Items.Add(2);
            p2.setStatus("A");
        }
    }
}
```

----------Phone1 Class---------

```
public partial class phone1 : Form
{
    public phone1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string status;
    public void setStatus(string Status)
    {
        status = Status;
    }

    public string returnStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void receiveCall(int callerNumber)
    {
        setStatus("Busy");
        btnCall.Text = "Answer";
        textBox1.Text = "Phone " + callerNumber + " Calling.";
    }

    public void makeCall(int number)
    {
        phone2 p2 = new phone2();
        network net = new network();

        MessageBox.Show(p2.returnStatus()); // this line not returing status of phone2
        if (p2.returnStatus() == "A")
        {
            net.processCall(number);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Receiver Busy";
        }
    }

    public TextBox TextBox1
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1;
        }
    }

    private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string number = textBox1.Text;
        int numberInt = Convert.ToInt16(number);

        makeCall(numberInt);
    }

    string phoneNo = "";
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        phoneNo = phoneNo + btn2.Text;
        textBox1.Text = phoneNo;
    }
}
```

-------------phone2 Class--------------

```
public partial class phone2 : phone1
{
    public phone2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to clean up the code, but it would be helpful for you to edit it down further to remove any code not related to the problem.  Most people aren't willing to dig through an entire program to find where the problem is occurring.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where do you expect `p2.Status` to be set in the 3 lines between creating it and showing the status? The constructor doesn't set it. You're not explicitly setting it in `makeCall`.

Answer (score 1):

The routine makeCall is creating a new instance of phone2 and calling returnStatus next. The problem is that the string "status" is not Being initialized with any value when p2 is created, so, the returno value will never be "A" and you will always fail the test.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do? what approach should I take?

Comment: Emdadul, you have to "re-think" your approach. You have 2 "phones" and a "network". First, they are separately entities. So, network shouldn't create it's own instances of "phone". Instead, you could maintain a list of available "phones" and on startup, all "phones" would send a message to the network saying "I'm available". Phones than can ask for a connection and the network can connect (if the other number is available, or send back a "busy" warning if the phone isn't available or is occupied. In the end, when one of the phones finish, the net mark both as available again. 
Just an idea :)

Comment: many thanks for your comment, I will definitely give it a go.